# Javascript Hitting "Enter" when hover on AutoComplete

Tags: javascript

I have some basic code for an AutoComplete search box.  When autocomplete options appear, I can click the option to go to a URL.  I can use my arrow keys to go through the autocomplete options, but cannot click "Enter" to go to the URL.

Can someone help with being able to select the option when I'm hovered on it and click "enter"?  Please no jquery solutions.

  [No Name]jr[at]aol.com
  Sara Smithssmith[at]yahoo.com
  John Doejdoe[at]aol.com@yahoo.com

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Remember for these type of questions, it's better to create a **jsFiddle** and put your code there. So then you'll have your answer sooner.